# Grails Spring Security - custom UserDetailsService makes authenticatedUser null

Tags: grails, spring-security

I made a custom `UserDetailsService` that makes the username in a login case insensitive, and it's working, however, all controllers (which were working previously) are now returning null for `authenticatedUser`.

Right before requesting `authenticatedUser`, `isLoggedIn()` returns true and `getPrincipal()` returns the logged in user.

Here's the custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
package com.mydomain

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException

class CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean hasRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Person.withTransaction { status ->
            Person user = Person.findByEmailIlike(username)

            if(!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {
                new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)
            }

            new GrailsUser(user.username, user.password, user.enabled, !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired, !user.accountLocked, authorities, user.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you aren't setting the `id` property when you create the `GrailsUser`. Looking at the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/controllerMetaClassMethods.html)  the `id` is used to locate the `authenticatedUser`.

Comment: At the end of the new GrailsUser() I'm passing in user.id. I double checked and it's passing a valid ID. It looked to be the right way to do it, is there a different way?